# How to compress large data set in raw format for volume rendering?

Tags: compression, cuda, large-data-volumes

I have a large data set which I want to render using CUDA. The size of data set is about 5GB. It is in 8 bit raw format. Is there a way to compress the data set to sizes less than 3 GB?

The loss in quality/details is fine with me. The reduced data set should also be in 8-bit raw format.

Comment: Before you concern yourself with compressing the source data: are you sure the texture hardware supports large-enough extents (i.e. maximum width, height and depth) for your use case?

Comment: It'd be implemented as a multi-resolution image i.e. resolution would increase as you zoom in, so the extents should not pose a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers which could fit your need, although it really depends on what you want to do with your data set.

1) Is your data set an 8-bit Grey image ?
If not : how is defined 'a loss of quality and details' ?

2) Do you need to access "any point" anywhere in the image ? Is the data set going to be access in "batch processing" or "random access" mode ?

3) Have you considered using basic Texture Compression algorithms, such as DXTC (or any other compression algorithm supported by your hardware, presumably NVidia) ?

Comment: 1) Yes. It is 8-bit Grey image.
2) It would be random access mode as I plan to use ray casting for volume rendering.
3) No, I didn't know about it. I'd look into it.

Comment: OK, then hardware compression seems the way to go, due to the "random access mode" requirement. There are several algorithms available, but they all use about the same technique : cut the image into little squares, and apply a small differential formula on it. Typical compression ratio is between 1/4 and 1/6.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to implement volume rendering of large volume data sets：

(1)use compressed format to load volume data into GPU memory

(2)use out-of-core GPU volume rendering